# Python: iterate through dictionary and create list with results

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I would like to iterate through a dictionary in Python in the form of:

```
dictionary = {
    'company': {
         0: 'apple',
         1: 'berry',
         2: 'pear'
     },
     'country': {
         0:'GB',
         1:'US',
         2:'US'
     }
}
```

To grab for example:
every `[company, country]` if `country` is `"US"`

So I get a list in the form:

```
[["berry", "US"], ["pear", "US"]]
```

Comment: I suppose the key `3` for `"pear"` should be `2`?

Comment: It usually helps to ask yourself, how would you do that without a program, and what's the logic you'd follow. I guess, you would take each pair from the first dict and find a corresponding item from the second one, then add the values to the result and move to the next pair. That suggests using a loop with a couple of operations in it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your keys are strings as well and the output is a list of lists, where the elements are strings, too. Then this problem can be solved via list comprehension.

The idea is to use list comprehension to fill the list of `[company, country]`-lists, but only if the country is `'US'`. `key` represents the keys of the inner dictionaries (i.e 0, 1, 2).

```
dictionary = {'company': {0: 'apple', 1: 'berry', 2: 'pear'}, 'country': {0: 'GB', 1: 'US', 2:'US'}}
y = [[dictionary['company'][key], dictionary['country'][key]] for key in dictionary['country'] if dictionary['country'][key] == 'US']
```

It returns

```
[['berry', 'US'], ['pear', 'US']]
```

Comment: thanks it works nicely ,i struggled from the k,v concept in dictionary to iterate vs x,y enumerate(list)

Comment: @user3083330 Maybe it is easier then to write it like this ``y = [[dictionary['company'][key], dictionary['country'][key]] for (key, country) in dictionary['country'].iteritems() if country == 'US']`` where you find the ``(key,value)=...`` part, where key is 0, 1 or 2 and the value is ``country`` which take the values ``'US'`` or ``'GB'``.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = []
list(map(lambda x: myList.append(x) if x[1]=='US' else None,
    zip(dictionary['company'].values(), dictionary['country'].values())))
```