# How to iterate through dictionary in a list

Tags: python

I tried to extract out the information of distance, duration, and status of the list of dictionary below and I am stuck

So far I have

```
distance = [{u'distance': {u'text': u'248 mi', u'value': 398525},
  u'duration': {u'text': u'3 hours 59 mins', u'value': 14346},
  u'status': u'OK'},
 {u'distance': {u'text': u'2,306 mi', u'value': 3711303},
  u'duration': {u'text': u'1 day 9 hours', u'value': 120030},
  u'status': u'OK'}]
## What is the distance (in miles) between location x and location y?
for i in range(len(distance)):
    for key in distance[i]:
        print(distance[i][key])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: iterate through dictionary and create list with results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708666/python-iterate-through-dictionary-and-create-list-with-results)

Comment: What are you stuck on? This code does what the question asks. Could you provide your desired output? For reference see [mre].

Comment: the above link is not similar to my case and i do not think it answer my question yet. The output should distance = [248,2306], duration =['3 hours 59 min','1 day 9 hours']

Comment: Will the list `distance` always have 2 elements (of dictionaries) inside and you want to get the values of each? Where does location x and location y come into picture. Are we just extracting the values `'text'` and making it available?

Comment: Yes the format will stay the same. The location x is the first element where distance from x to y is 248 mi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm assuming you want the value indicated under "distance->duration->value"? You could directly access it via indexing
- meantime, you could iterate through lists and dictionaries directly without using `range(len(<array>))`

my suggestion below:

```py
distance = [{u'distance': {u'text': u'248 mi', u'value': 398525},
  u'duration': {u'text': u'3 hours 59 mins', u'value': 14346},
  u'status': u'OK'},
 {u'distance': {u'text': u'2,306 mi', u'value': 3711303},
  u'duration': {u'text': u'1 day 9 hours', u'value': 120030},
  u'status': u'OK'}]
## What is the distance (in miles) between location x and location y?
for d in distance:
    print(d['distance']['value'])
```

output

```
398525
3711303
```